# Show image using setTimeout and for loop in array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

```
images: [
    {
        img: 'car_0.png',
        time: 3000,
    },
    {
        img: 'car_1.png',
        time: 500,
    },
    {
        img: 'car_2.png',
        time: 500,
    },
    {
        img: 'car_3.png',
        time: 1000,
    },
],
```

I need display image in my page. `time` is the time when the image should be displayed on the page. For example:

The first photo car_0.png is displayed on the page for 3 seconds. After 3 seconds it changes to the second image, which is displayed for 0.5 seconds...

I have writen this method but not working:

```
if(images !== undefined) {
    for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.images = images[i].img
        }, images[i].time + images[i + 1].time)
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***

I change my method to:

```
if(images !== undefined) {
    let time
    for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if(i > 0) {
            time = time + images[i].time
        }
        else {
            time = images[i].time
        }
        console.log(time)
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.images = images[i].img
        }, time)
    }
}
```

Now in `console.log(time)` I have value:

```
3000
3500
4000
5000
```

But still not working correctly, the first picture should appear immediately and be displayed for 3 seconds. Now appears after 3 seconds

Comment: `images[i + 1].time` will break the loop on the last iteration

Comment: You want the sum of all previous "images" + the current one as timeout, not the current one + the next one.

Comment: You need `img` element to show the image, then change `src` property of that element instead of overriding your `images` array members with undefineds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `img` element in html and change its `src` attribute using javascript.

To show images in order, you could use a generator function.

1. Create a generator function that yields an image object after specific amount of time.
2. Create another function that calls this generator function to get the image object, gets the value of the `img` property from the returned image object and sets it as value of `src` attribute on the `img` element.

   This function also creates a timeout which expires after the time equal to the `time` property of the current image object. When timeout expires, this function calls itself again to get the next image from the generator function and displays that image.

   These steps are repeated until there are no more images to display.

```js
const images = [
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/0/100', time: 3000 },
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/100', time: 500 },
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/10/100', time: 500 },
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/100/100', time: 1000 }
];

const img = document.querySelector('img');

function* getImage() {
  for (let image of images) {
    yield image;
  }
}

const imageGenerator = getImage();

function showNextImage() {
  const image = imageGenerator.next().value;

  if (!image) return;
  
  img.src = image.img;
  
  setTimeout(showNextImage, image.time);
};

showNextImage();
```

```html
<img src=""/>
```

Alternatively, Instead of using a generator function to get an image object, you could just use a variable that keeps track of the index of the image that is currently displayed and each image object accessed using this index variable.

```js
const images = [
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/0/100', time: 3000 },
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/100', time: 500 },
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/10/100', time: 500 },
    { img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/100/100', time: 1000 }
];

const img = document.querySelector('img');
let index = 0;

function showNextImage() {
  const image = images[index++];

  if (!image) return;
  
  img.src = image.img;
  setTimeout(showNextImage, image.time);
};

showNextImage();
```

```html
<img src=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code, it works for me:

```js
var images = [
        {
            img: 'car_0.png',
            time: 3000,
        },
        {
            img: 'car_1.png',
            time: 500,
        },
        {
            img: 'car_2.png',
            time: 500,
        },
        {
            img: 'car_3.png',
            time: 1000,
        },
    ]
    var currentImage = 0;
    function showImages(){
        
        let img = images[currentImage];
        console.log(img.img);
        setTimeout(function () {
            currentImage++;
            if(currentImage<images.length){
              showImages();
            }
        }, img.time);
    };
    showImages();
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
change first line's `:` to `=`,
replace last `,` with `;`,
and remove `,` from after the last object in the array.

Second, try this code:

```
function displayImage(images, i=0) {
  if(images.length==0) return;
  console.log(images[i].img); // replace with whatever you want to do
  i++;
  if(i==images.length) i=0;
  setTimeout(displayImage,images[i].time,images,i);
}
```

call with:

```
displayImage(images);
```

or:

```
displayImage(images, 2); // if you want to start with the 3rd
```

Answer (score -1):

do something like this using a promise function:

```js
const images = [{
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/0/100',
    time: 3000,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/10/100',
    time: 500,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/100/100',
    time: 500,
  },
  {
    img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1000/100',
    time: 1000,
  },
];

const waitNext = ({
  time
}) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}



async function displayImages(images) {
  for (const image of images) {
    document.getElementById('img').src = image.img;
    await waitNext(image);
  }
}

displayImages(images)
```

```html
<img id="img" src="" />
```

Comment: _"The first photo car_0.png is displayed on the page for 3 seconds. After 3 seconds it changes to the second image, which is displayed for 0.5 seconds..."_

Comment: Your edit doesn't solve the requirement from my first comment.

Comment: @Andreas  idk i didn't get it at first here's another update

Comment: And where is the part that "displays" the image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217608/discussion-between-g-aziz-and-andreas).

Comment: @G.aziz OP wants first image to be displayed immediately. [Here's the fixed version of your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/flDpGCSOuPh83UeU?open=lib%2Fscript.js)